# Clan, guild, team, faction or group?

Tags: user-experience

I don't know if this is the right question for Stackexchange because it is based on opinion, so excuse me if it's not.

I'm currently developing a mobile leisure game in a cartoon style where players build and expand their kingdom, in a medieval setting. Users can be part of a group to help each other, trade goods, communicate together,  and support each other when attacked. The game is NOT a fight game only. Developing and maintaining your city and the citizens is an important aspect, socializing with other players is key, and the target audience are both men and **women**.

I'm really confused how I should name such groups where you can be part of. Clans, guilds, teams, groups or factions: all of them are possible. When should I use which name? And what would fit my situation the best? It's really important to let users feel they are part of a group. Not just a fighting group, but a group both men and women feel attracted to. A fraction for example would not be the best I think.

I realize this heavily depends on opinions. Buy are there any sources that could help me? What do you feel attracted to? What fits my situation the best?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard. I have seen all kinds of names used for different kinds of player-groups. Which one is appropriate mostly depends the scenario of the game and how you intend players to interact with each other and how you expect them to interact as a group with the rest of the game world.

When your game has a medieval theme, you might want to look how historic cooperations of medieval rulers called themselves: Empires, Alliances, Federations, Pacts, Leagues.

Another way to come to a conclusion is to ask yourself how *the players* would call their groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Or even better, you could do a survey with your current players or with players of similar games as the one that you are building.

Comment: Please use the comments to ask further details :)